# Disabling fp-model strict when using ifort with f2py

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, fortran, f2py

I'm using `f2py` to offload performance critical sections of my python code to fortran. I have two fortran compilers, `gfortran` and `ifort`. Since the code I run will be on intel processors, `ifort` is usually faster. But for the most critical part of my code, I observe the opposite, with `gfortran` being faster by 40%! After inspecting the actual command line `ifort` is being called with, I noticed that `f2py` appends `-fp-model strict` to the command line no matter what I specify in the `FFLAGS` environment variable. I suspect that this is the cause of the `ifort` slowness.

Is there a way to make `f2py` stop enforcing this floating point model? I've tried both adding `-fp-model fast` to `FFLAGS` and `f2py`'s `--f90flags` argument, but while they appear on the final command line, they do so before the strict flag, and are therefore overridden. While I appreciate support for NaNs etc., it is not worth a 40% slowdown.

Here is my `f2py` command line:

```
FFLAGS="-openmp -Ofast -fPIC" f2py --fcompiler=intelem -c -m pmat_core_32 pmat_core_32.f90 -liomp5
```

and here are the flags that are actually passed to `ifort`, according to the `f2py` output:

```
-FI -openmp -Ofast -fPIC -xhost -openmp -fp-model strict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flags `-xhost -openmp -fp-model strict` come from

```
def get_flags_opt(self):
    return ['-xhost -openmp -fp-model strict']
```

in the file `site-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/intel.py` for the classes that invoke ifort.

You have two options to modify the behavior of these flags:

- call `f2py` with the `--noopt` flag to suppress these flags
- call `f2py` with the `--opt='blah'` to override these flags

You can get the flags you desire with:

```
FFLAGS="-fPIC" f2py --fcompiler=intelem --opt='-xhost -0fast -openmp' -c -m pmat_core_32 pmat_core_32.f90 -liomp5
```